# iPhone log for actions like deleting text conversations?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, logs, messages

I recently found one of my long-running text conversations cleared.  I may have deleted it accidentally, but I would like to know when I did.  Is there a system log that logs information at this level?  Maybe in /var/log/ ?

Comment: This is a great question, but as far as I know, there aren't any logs that capture those events. I could be wrong, however. Let's see if somebody else has some more knowledge.

Comment: There is a an app in Cydia that just came out. It's called `syslogman`. You could try downloading it and seeing if it displays what you're looking for. There are logs for installing/uninstalling applications, so maybe there is an SMS folder in `/var/mobile/Library/Logs`. Could you see whether or not it's present?

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 had no such logs that I am aware of. To my knowledge, neither does iOS 6. The system logs record more "important" information regarding system operation and such.